# operational transformation based database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, database, operational-transform

Is there such kind of database with operational transformation supported running on Linux? it is better if it also has a rails adapter.

I know [CEDA](http://www.cedanet.com.au/cedapresentation2007_27.shtml) is one which has many features are what I need, but it won't run on Linux and it is closed source and has no trial version available, if anyone knows one please let me know, thanks.

Comment: BTW, Ceda does have a Linux port these days.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, but you could use a flat file database, then store versions in Git, which would allow you to commit, revert, and cherrypick.